# Can PHP curl methods upload a file and a string with a leading @ character in the same request?

Tags: php, curl

I'd like to construct a POST request using PHP curl_* methods that does the following:

1. uploads a file (so the request must be submitted as multipart/form-data)
2. sends a string of text, where the string starts with an "@" character

For example, the following code works because there is no leading "@" character in the string of text:

```
<?php

$postfields = array(
    'upload_file' => '@file_to_upload.png',
    'upload_text' => 'text_to_upload'
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/upload-test');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

But, it breaks if the string starts with an "@" character which causes curl looks for a non-existent file named "text_to_upload" (Note that the only change is the addition of a leading "@" character in the upload_text field):

```
<?php

$postfields = array(
    'upload_file' => '@file_to_upload.png',
    'upload_text' => '@text_to_upload'
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/upload-test');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

So... is it possible to send text with a leading "@" character while uploading a file at the same time using the curl_* methods in PHP?

The end result (if possible) should be the equivalent of this command line use of curl:

```
curl -F 'upload_=@file_to_upload.png' --form-string 'upload_text=@text_to_upload' 'http://example.com/upload-test'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Prepend the string with the null character`"\0"`:

```
<?php
    $postfields = array(
        'upload_file' => '@file_to_upload.png',
        'upload_text' => sprintf("\0%s", '@text_to_upload')
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/upload-test');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: This method works for publishing to Twitter as it ignores the NUL character. Posting to Facebook results in ��@justin and tries to actually render the NUL character instead of ignoring it. Is there any other solution anyone knows about?

Comment: I've had a good go at it and can't seem to find a clean solution :( appending whitespace with `preg_replace('/^@/', ' @', $text)` looks like the only way forward for now.

Comment: Worth noting that "As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files can be sent using CURLFile." [source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), [CurlFile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative 1**

Most probably you will have to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php) the parameter.

```
$postfields = array(
    'upload_file' => '@file_to_upload.png',
    'upload_text' => urlencode('@text_to_upload')
);
```

Also, [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php) at server side.

**Alternative 2**

Simply add an space at the beginning of `upload_text` regardless of its content.

```
$postfields = array(
    'upload_file' => '@file_to_upload.png',
    'upload_text' => ' @text_to_upload'
);
```